# Correlation between a pandas Series and a whole DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a series of values and I'm looking to compute the pearson correlation with every row of a given table.

How do I do I do that?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

v = [-1, 5, 0, 0, 10, 0, -7]
v1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
v2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
v3 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

s = pd.Series(v)
df = pd.DataFrame([v1, v2, v3], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

# Here I expect ot do df.corrwith(s) - but won't work
```

Using `Series.corr()` to calculate, the expected output is

```
-0.1666666666666666  # correlation with the first row
0.83914639167827343  # correlation with the second row
-0.35355339059327379 # correlation with the third row
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need same `index` of `Series` as `columns` of `DataFrame` for align `Series` by `DataFrame` and add `axis=1` in [`corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) for row-wise correlation:

```
s1 = pd.Series(s.values, index=df.columns)
print (s1)
a    -1
b     5
c     0
d     0
e    10
f     0
g    -7
dtype: int64

print (df.corrwith(s1, axis=1))
0   -0.166667
1    0.839146
2   -0.353553
dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (df.corrwith(pd.Series(v, index=df.columns), axis=1))
0   -0.166667
1    0.839146
2   -0.353553
dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

You can specify columns and use subset:

```
cols = ['a','b','e']

print (df[cols])
   a  b  e
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  0

print (df[cols].corrwith(pd.Series(v, index=df.columns), axis=1))
0   -0.891042
1    0.891042
2   -0.838628
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, what a rookie mistake... exactly what I needed

Comment: No problem, how would you go about that if the dataframe had more columns that you would want to disregard? meaning you'd want to compute correlation with only the matching columns to index while disregarding the others

Comment: I'll check it later, but actually I'm debugging some other issue right now - thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful to those concerned with performance.
I have found this runs in half the time compared to pandas corrwith.

Your data:

```
import pandas as pd
v = [-1, 5, 0, 0, 10, 0, -7]
v1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
v2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
v3 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]    
df = pd.DataFrame([v1, v2, v3], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
```

The solution (note that v is not transformed into a series):

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
s_corrs = df.apply(lambda x: pearsonr(x.values, v)[0], axis=1)
```